# Сервер уходит в ребут

Tags: сервер, железо

Доброго времечка, господа!

Поставил на ночь серв (Xeon 2GHz Quad-core, ASUS DSBV-DX, 4GB) на стрестест (stresslinux). Запустил burnP6. С утра обнаружил, что серв постоянно ребутится, пробегает экран диагностики, и ребут. В биос заходит, пара секунд и ребут.

Где копать?

Comment: Посмотрел отзывы, народ пишет на серверном железе работает отвратительно, вылеты и сбой загрузки. На десктопах все типа работает. Гляньте вот здесь, это альтернатива вроде http://www.inquisitor.ru/about/Как система ведет себя на обычной ОС (LiveCD).Ребут может вызывать память или недостаточное питание (сбой в цепи питания).

Comment: (A long time ago...) Проблема была действительно в памяти. Спасибо.